# Apache couchDB service terminates on Windows 10 Single language

Tags: couchdb

After rebboting the machine the Apache CouchDB service seems to be stopped, if we manually starts , its getting started.
Ihave checked the eventviewer  got the folowing errors. Kindly help me t o resolve this

1. The apache couchDB service terminated with following error: The configuration registry key could not be read9 Event ID:7023)
2. Apache Couch DB01d14dda41ed1200: could not get keys for erlang service ( Event ID :17)

Answer (score 3):

For some reason during Windows 10 startup, erlsrv.exe looks for a registry key using InternalServiceName instead of SName. You can't just rename the key in Regedit or the CouchDb service won't be able to be restarted after boot, so you need to duplicate it.

Run Regedit, export the key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\Apache CouchDB
```

to a file, edit the file and change the key to

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Ericsson\Erlang\ErlSrv\1.1\Apache Couch DB01d14dda41ed1200
```

then import the file into Regedit. (Obviously replace 01d14dda41ed1200 with the value found in the InternalServiceName key in your file.)